# After installing conda packages, login name disappears from Linux terminal

Tags: linux, conda

After installing any conda package, login name disappears from Linux terminal. For reference please see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyllA.png).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed `conda 22.9.0`. Changes were made to the shell interface requiring a one-time re-initialization of `conda`:

```
conda init bash
```

After running the above command, you will need to restart your shell for the changes to take effect.

See: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11885